# VBScript - email when file not created today

Tags: vbscript

Goal: To run a VBScript that checks a folder daily, and reports if no files were saved to it that day. Ignore the files that exist from previous days.

I need to check if a file was not created that day and send an email. If a file was created that day then i want the script to do nothing - no notification.  I found this code, but it does the opposite and sends the email if the file is present and does nothing if it is missing:

```
option explicit
dim myMail
dim fileSystem, folder, file  
dim path
path = "C:\Temp"   
Set fileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Dim myDate
myDate =  dateadd("d", -1, FormatDateTime(Now, 2))
Set folder = fileSystem.GetFolder(path)   
for each file in folder.Files
    if file.DateCreated > myDate then  
    'WScript.Echo file.Name & " last modified at " & file.DateCreated   
        SendEmail 
    'WScript.Echo "this should have sent an email."   
    end if  
next

Function SendEmail()   
    'this works
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea that you are done, if today's file is found, but have to check **all** files to be sure, that today's file is missing, the logic would be:

```
found = False
For all files in folder
    If today's file found
       found = True
       Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not found Then
   Send Email
End If
```